# How can make point, assist Leaders in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 'stats' table and 'id','playername','point','asist' coloumns..
I want to make like this picture's tables.

[image]

Example:
[image]

How can I do that with only 1 query?

Comment: You mean you want all records to be printed in specified order?

Comment: yea. i want to make like that pic.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/JKLka.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `UNION ALL` operator for that

```
SELECT 'Points','Leaders' UNION ALL
SELECT Playername,point order by point desc UNION ALL
SELECT 'AsIst','Leaders' UNION ALL
SELECT Playername,asist order by asist desc
```

Hope this helps.